# 乱数で変化させているはずが値が同一となってしまう

Tags: ruby

Rubyを最近使い始めまして，勉強中の身です．
熱雑音生成のプログラムを書いているのですが，UnitTestをしたところ，乱数で降ってるはずなのに値が更新されず，同一のままになってしまいます．
デバッグをしていますが，原因がわかりません．
ご教授お願い致します．
詳細は以下のコードになります．

長文失礼しました.

---

```
def BoxMullerNoise
    rnd = Random.new
    return BoxMuller.new_create(rnd)
end

class BoxMuller
   attr_accessor :_urng
   attr_accessor :_x
   attr_accessor :_y
   attr_accessor :_saveIns

   def self.new_create(urng)
       obj = self.new
       obj._urng = urng
       obj._x = urng.rand(1.0)
       obj._y = urng.rand(1.0)

       obj._saveInst = obj  # インスタンスの保存

       return obj
   end

   def value    # この中身の_x, _yが，popfrontをUnitTestでしているのに更新されない
       p _x
       p _y
       return Math.sqrt((-2.0) * Math.log(_x)) * Complex(Math.cos(2*Math::PI*_y), Math.sin(2*Math::PI*_y))
   end

   @@empty = false

   def popfront
       p "BoxMullerクラス内です"
       _x = _urng.rand(1.0)
       _y = _urng.rand(1.0)
   end

   def seed(seed)
       srand(seed)
   end

   def save
       _keepInst = _saveInst

       _keepInst._urng = _urng

       return _keepInst
   end
end


def noisePower(bandwidth, tempK)
    return bandwidth * tempK * BoltzmannConst
end


class ThermalNoise
   attr_accessor :_rnd
   attr_accessor :_gain
   attr_accessor :_saveInst

   def self.new_create(sampFreq, tempK, seed = Random.new.seed)
       obj = self.new
       obj._rnd = BoxMullerNoise()
       obj._gain = Math.sqrt(noisePower(sampFreq, tempK) / 2)
       obj._rnd.seed(seed)

       obj._saveInst = obj  # インスタンスの保存

       return obj
   end


   def value
       return _rnd.value * _gain
   end

   @@empty = false

   def popfront
       p "ThermalNoiseクラス内です"
       _rnd.popfront
   end

   def save
       _keepInst = _saveInst

       _keepInst._rnd = _saveInst._rnd.save

       p _keepInst
       return _keepInst
   end
end


# UnitTest
class UnitTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def test_ThermalNoise
       buf = Array.new(64*1024)
       rndSeed = 114514
       thermalNoise = ThermalNoise.new_create((20*10**6)*4, 300, rndSeed + 123321)

       (0 ... 4).each{ |i|
           thermalNoise.popfront # BoxMullerクラスの_x, _yを変えているはずなのに
           thermalNoise.value    # ここで同じ値が表示されてしまう
       }
   end
end
```

Comment: BoxMuller.popfront() メソッド内でインスタンス変数ではなくローカル変数に値を代入しています。`_x = _urng.rand(1.0)` ではなく、`@_x = _urng.rand(1.0)` とするのではないでしょうか(`_y` も同様)。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。@を付けたところ期待した動作をしました。ありがとうございます！ 加えて、ご指摘があればなのですが、上記のプログラムで文法的に好ましくない箇所があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   def popfront
       p "BoxMullerクラス内です"
       _x = _urng.rand(1.0)
       _y = _urng.rand(1.0)
   end
```

を

```
   def popfront
       p "BoxMullerクラス内です"
       self._x = _urng.rand(1.0)
       self._y = _urng.rand(1.0)
   end
```

のようにしてください。

Rubyでは`a = b`と言う表現は常にローカル変数`a`へ`b`を代入するとみなされます。ローカル変数`a`が未定義であれば、同時にローカル変数`a`が定義されることになります。`_x = _urng.rand(1.0)`という表現もローカル変数`_x`の定義と代入になり、インタンスメソッドの呼び出しにはなりません。インスタンスメソッドとして扱いたい場合は`self._x = _urng.rand(1.0)`というようにレシーバーを明記する必要があります。

さて、全体的に言えることはRubyっぽくないことです。何か別の言語で作られた物を無理矢理移植したように思えます。たぶん、どこかで無理が出て、破綻します。

- 初期化には`initialize`を使いましょう。特殊なことをしない限り、クラスメソッドを新しい`new`もどきを作る必要はありません。
- クラス内の処理はインスタンス変数を使いましょう。`attre_accessor`等は外部にインスタンス変数を見せるための手段です。外部に見せる必要が無いのであれば、使うべきではありません。
- Rubyのクラスは構造体ではありません。C++/D/Javaのように構造体の拡張と考えてはいけません。
- 郷には入れば郷に従えです。Rubyでは2スペースのインデント、ローカル変数やメソッドはスネークケースが推奨されています。その他は[Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide)を参考にしてください。